# Inconsistent colors by minted

Tags: minted

Consider

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,onecolumn,openright,final,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{scala}
  def uncurry[A,B,C](f: A => B => C): (A, B) => C 
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why arrows have different colors? Is there a way to make all arrows green, or is it a design decision?

Comment: I get [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxG0b.png) Pygments version 2.9.0

Comment: The same with Pygments version 2.11.2